# Chef git asks for username

Tags: git, chef-infra

I am using chef and no matter how hard I try, no matter getting my proper ssh files, git still asks for my username.

How can I set it up such that it always has my username?

```
git data_bag_item("users", "deployer")["home"] do 
  repository "https://github.com/vvvv/vvvvvvvvvvv"
  user data_bag_item("users", "deployer")["username"]
  ssh_wrapper "ssh -i #{data_bag_item('users', 'deployer')['home']}/.ssh/git_user_rsa" #the path to our private key file
  timeout 10
end
```

Comment: You are using an HTTPS URL and having problems with SSH? How does that fit together?

Comment: @StephenKing that was the problem! Make that an answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an `https` URL with `ssh_wrapper`, which makes little sense.

Comment: BTW, now i run into this problem: `STDERR: fatal: cannot exec '/home/deployer/.ssh/git_user_rsa': Permission denied` seen it before?

Comment: I think you understand the `ssh_wrapper` wrong. It should be an executable script, not the private key.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh_wrapper` needs to be the path to a script, not a command like that. You can either write out that script using a template resource or you could skip the `$GIT_SSH` bit and write out a `.ssh/config` file to the correct user with the needed config options. Also remember you'll probably want to disable host-key checking for non-interactive situations.